# How to automate already installed ios Apps using Appium

Tags: mobile, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

How to automate already installed ios Apps using Appium. I want to automate like whatsap ebay and other installed apps in my iphone using appium.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to automate the app if you know the bundleId of the application. For WhatsApp the bundleId is `net.whatsapp.WhatsApp`

If your Appium set up is correct and have python installed then, start an Appium Server and Run the sample python code. You can attach the session to the Appium inspector to inspect the elements.

```
from appium import webdriver
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '12.4.6'
desired_caps['name'] = 'Sample Test'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone 6'
desired_caps['udid'] = 'add_your_device_udid_here'
desired_caps["bundleId"] = "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp"
desired_caps["noReset"] = True
desired_caps["newCommandTimeout"] = 50000
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bundle ID capability with existing capabilities.

```
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "udid");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "12.4");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
        caps.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
        caps.setCapability("bundleId", "com.company.appname");
        caps.setCapability("usePrebuiltWDA", true);

        IOSDriver<WebElement>  driver = new IOSDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), caps)
```

I have added UDID capability which is used for real device.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
{
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "iPhone",
  "udid": "...",
  "xcodeOrgId": "...",
  "platformVersion": "xx.y",
  "updatedWDABundleId": "com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner"
}
```